# heroku no such app

Tags: heroku, dns, sinatra

I followed the docs at Heroku and Zerigo to set up a custom domain for MYAPP.heroku.com. When I navigate to myapp.heroku.com, everything works fine. But when I navigate to myapp.com or www.myapp.com, I get the error "Heroku | No such app"

```
host myapp.heroku.com
myapp.heroku.com is an alias for proxy.heroku.com.
[.....]
```

looks good, and

```
host www.myapp.com
www.myapp.com is an alias for proxy.heroku.com.
[.....]
```

looks good too. But I still get "Heroku | No such app".

totally baffled at this point

Comment: Maybe you pointed to myapp.heroku.com instead of myapp.herokuAPP.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DNS entries look fine - provided you've added www.myapp.com as a custom domain to your application on Heroku then it should work fine. You can check this by viewing the application from the 'My Apps' tab on heroku.com and making sure the custom domain is listed in the domains section as 'www.myapp.com'.

If thats there then I'd log a ticket with support as you're doing everything right.

UPDATE: Heroku Status was just updated with a problem surrounding custom domains, it's likely that this is your problem - https://status.heroku.com/

HEROKU UPDATE: Engineers are still investigating the source of issues regarding custom domains. We have determined that only domains added or updated in the past 48 hours should be affected.
We'll continue to provide more information as it becomes available.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it has looked perfect on the My Apps tab all along

Comment: Then I'd suggest you get in touch with support as if you've done all of this then it's correct.

Comment: yup, I just got caught up in the glitch. Thanks for the updates, John

Comment: For anyone who comes looking here, I faced this problem when I had `myapp.com` in custom domains in heroku settings but not `www.myapp.com`

Comment: @PulkitGoyal that was incredibly helpful!!!

For anyone else finding this: worked for me to point `www.myapp.com` CNAME record to `myapp.herokuapp.com`. Set a redirect record from `myapp.com` to `www.myapp.com`. And doublecheck that `www.myapp.com` is listed in Heroku Settings / Domains. Also, delete any stray A records from Zerigo.